# Call the_content in tooltip attribute wp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this [**tooltip**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-tooltips/).

In this tooptip, I want to call image and content.

`image` is showing up correctly but text is not showing up in tooptip. When I use `the_content` and `$content` to call text its showing error.

I have used `$thumbnail[0]` to call image.

Here is code, i have call image and content:

```
add_shortcode('personnel', 'gdl_personnal_shortcode');
function gdl_personnal_shortcode( $atts ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts(array("size"=>'1/4', 'num_fetch'=>4, "category"=>''), $atts) );

    global $personnal_div_size_num_class, $sidebar_type;
    $personnal = '';
    $personnal_row_size = 0;
    $item_size = $personnal_div_size_num_class[$size][$sidebar_type];

    $post_temp = query_posts(array('post_type'=>'personnal',
        'personnal-category' => $category, 'posts_per_page'=>$num_fetch)
    );        

    $personnal = $personnal . '<div class="personnal-item-holder">';
    while( have_posts() ){ the_post();  

        $ret_size = return_item_size($size, $personnal_row_size, 'personnal-item-wrapper');
        $personnal_row_size = $ret_size['row-size'];
        $personnal = $personnal . $ret_size['return'];
        $personnal = $personnal . '<div class="personnal-item">';

        $personnal = $personnal . '<div class="personnal-title">';
        $personnal = $personnal . get_the_title();
        $personnal = $personnal . '</div>';         
        $ids=get_the_ID();
        $position = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'personnal-option-position', true );
        if( !empty($position) ){
            $personnal = $personnal . '<div class="personnal-position">' . $position . "</div>";
        }

        $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id , $item_size );
        $alt_text = get_post_meta($thumbnail_id , '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        if( !empty($thumbnail) ){
            $personnal = $personnal . '<div class="sc-tooltip" data-image="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" data-desc="'.'"><div class="personnal-thumbnail"><a href="#" onclick="abctext('.$ids.')" ><img src="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '"></a></div></div>';         
        }
```

the Tooltip loos like this:

[image]

But its has a text in the right side of the image which is not showing right now.

Comment: you need to post your complete code for the loop, as well as the errors you get when using `the_content` or `$content`

Comment: I just want the `content` in this attribute:-  `data-desc="" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made change in `$pearsonnal` string:-

```
$personnal = $personnal . '<div class="sc-tooltip" data-image="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" data-title="'.get_the_title().'" data-desc="'.strip_tags(do_shortcode( get_the_content() )).'"><div class="personnal-thumbnail"><a class="sc-team-link" href="#" onclick="abctext('.$ids.')" ><img src="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '"></a></div></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`get_the_content()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content) to return the post content as a variable rather than echoing it - you can assign this to `$content`. You can then append this to the `$personal` string.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$personnal .= '<div class="sc-tooltip" data-image="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" data-desc="'.$content.'"><div class="personnal-thumbnail"><a href="#" onclick="abctext('.$ids.')" ><img src="' . $thumbnail[0] . '" alt="' . $alt_text . '"></a></div></div>';
```

Comment: I did it so many time but it is displaying content over the image on page.

Comment: that is most likely a css issue

Comment: No, I mean its displaying content on page not in tooltip's box.